# $M^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ isometric immersion, $R\equiv 0\Rightarrow M$ locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

Let $f:M^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be an isometric immersion with $R\equiv 0$, where $R$ is the curvature tensor of $M$.

Can we say that $M$ is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I know that by Killing-Hopf theorem, we can say that $M$ is globaly isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$, provided that $M$ is complete and simply connected.

If I consider an open subset $U\subset M$, I can assume it to be simply connected, but not complete, so I can't apply Killing-Hopf.

I have the feeling that the answer is yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need an immersion, just a Riemannina manifold with zero $R$. This is essentially due to Reimann and is proved seven times in Spivak's Volume II of "A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry" starting, respectively on pages 197, 217, 241, 268, 274, 275 and 333. :) See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264898/who-first-proved-that-a-vanishing-riemann-tensor-is-sufficient-for-the-existence